# Enable a disabled edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have an edittext and a spinner with two items (" " and "1"). I disabled my edittext. Now what I want to do is enable my edittext when I select 1 in my spinner. But it's not enabling.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.......
                enable();
}

public void enable() {

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner1, android.R.layout.test_list_item));
        EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        edit1.setEnabled(false);

        if (s1.equals("1")) {
            edit1.setEnabled(true);
            edit1.setFocusable(true);
            edit1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement the method `onItemSelected`:

> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been
>   selected. This callback is invoked only when the newly selected
>   position is different from the previously selected position or if
>   there was no selected item.

```
public abstract void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use that onItemSelected at first because I didn't use it when I'm computing and giving values to the items on the spinner. I only use the getSelectedItem() method. But in this case where I want to enable other objects, getSelectedItem() is not working if I don't use onItemSelected.

Answer (score 0):

you should create on change item listener and set it to your spinner. This where you should post the code for enabling the edittext

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spinners onclick listener to 'hear' when the spinner has been interacted with, take the value of the spinner inside the onclick and manipulate other objects as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Extent OnItemSelectedListener of Spinner class and on

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}
```

Take the action of enabling and disabling the edit text.

Comment: what is parent? the spinner?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer getSelectedItem() instead of getItemAtPosition() because it's more flexible in getting the items and using them in statements.